# Symfony 2.3 FOSUserBundle does not find security.context

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I installed the FOS Bundle like mentioned in:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

After installation with composer and setting up the user class i always get:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
 The service "fos_user.security.login_manager" has a dependency on a non-exi
 stent service "security.context".
```

I checked the existence of the path and there is the contextinterface that is included in the fosuserbundle...
Using the console always aborts with the same error.
Anyone?

I enabled the bundle in appKernel (where the security bundle also is activated):

```
        ...
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        ...
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        ...
```

I added the config to the config.yml:

```
# fos UserBundle config
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: SDDB\MainBundle\Entity\User
```

I extended the routing.yml:

```
# USER AUTH STUFF

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

and the security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: paste php app/console container:debug security.context

Comment: have you ran the composer update ?

Comment: php app/console container:debug security.context
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
  The service "fos_user.security.login_manager" has a dependency on a non-exi
  stent service "security.context".

i now ran php composer update same exception plus:
...
  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i found the solution with help of a developer of FOS Bundle.

If you have a simmilar problem go through some basic stuff:

1. Is the FOS Bundle version fitting for your Symfony version?
2. Is security bundle proper installed?
3. Is it activated in the appkernel?
4. Is there a configuration file for it (security.yml)?
5. Is it inlcuded properly in the (main)config.yml?

I had a dumb typo in the include line at point (4)...

Answer (score 1):

Add :
- { resource: security.yml } to the import section in the main config.yml, it solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the service file exists (SecurityBundle\Resources\config\security.xml)
2. Check whether the service file is loaded (SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension.php)

Comment: thanks for the reply:
ad 1) yes it exists and 
        <parameter key="security.context.class">Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext</parameter>

ad 2) this too exists and loads the xml :/

Are the (active) services somewhere cached?