# Symfony2 error in security.yml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I need help with fixing this error and I am using symfony 2.6

> ServiceNotFoundException: The service "fos_user.security.login_manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.context".

Comment: what version of symfony are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony 2.3 FOSUserBundle does not find security.context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126393/symfony-2-3-fosuserbundle-does-not-find-security-context)

Comment: @tomasz i am using symfony2

Comment: ok, but which version specific? ``2.6``, ``2.7``

Comment: @tomasz using symfony 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`security.context` is deprecated since Symfony 2.6. You shouldn't have any problem because it's backward compatible, but you should check if you need to update your FOSUserBundle.

Run a composer update and check it.

More on the subject: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

If this doesn't solve, try the steps in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143572/2155387).